# Split dataset on a stratified and partitioned fashion

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, split

I am trying to split a Python Pandas dataframe in N chunks enforcing the following constraints:

1. All the chunks should be non-overlapping
2. The union of all the chunks should be equal to the overall dataset
3. The distribution of one column (namely, `_STRATA`) for each chunk should (approximately) follow the distribution of the same column in the total dataset (*stratified split*)
4. Given all the previous constraints, I also want to (approximately) minimize the amount of unique values associated to a second column (namely, `_PARTITION`) in each chunk. (*partitioned split*)

Also, the size of the dataframe might not be exactly divisible by N. So I should also tackle this edge-case.

Do you have any solution for this problem? I don't think I can rely on the Scikit-learn library. At the same time, I am not interested to have the exact optimal solution to the split problem: I am just interested to have a script or a library to perform this kind of operations having constraints 1 & 2 to be exactly enforced and constraints 3 & 4 enforced "in expectation".

I tried to use the Scikit-learn library to perform the split, but no KFold split or StratifiedSplit library has any configuration to solve the problem. I also tried to code it myself, but the solution I came up with seems quite buggy and doesn't yield the expected result.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold This should solve 1-3; it would give you the row indices for each chunk if you set it to split the _STRATA series. It would not satisfy 4.